# how to disable basic authentication when using kerberos on nginx?

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, kerberos, basic-authentication, nginx-reverse-proxy

---

**Foreword**

---

*In the main body of the question, the problem is described incorrectly. The correct explanation is described in the UPDATE block. Old text saved for history.*

---

My project consists of two parts: backend and frontend. The following locations are responsible for redirecting requests:

> ```
> location / {
>     root /opt/site/;
>     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
> }
>
> location /adminpanel {
>     proxy_pass http://192.168.1.4:4567;
> }
> location /api {
>     proxy_pass http://192.168.1.4:4567;
> }
> ```

The challenge is to redirect users to url `/auth` if there is no user login in the `$remote_user header`.
I tried to make the following construction:
in http I added:

```
 map $remote_user $var {
     default      0; 
     ""           1;  
     }
```

And in location `/` added:

```
if ($var) {   
      return 301 http://$server_name/auth;
    }
```

When I try to enter the site, I get an error in my browser:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

How do I fix my configuration file?

Thanks in advance!!!

**UPDATE**

My task is to configure Kerberos authentication on nginx. The backend is django. The idea is that when a request is made to api, nginx should perform kerberos authentication. But in case the user is not in the domain, then a redirect to the `/auth` authorization page must occur, so that the user can authenticate under an account that is registered in django CMS.

Authentication of domain users is successful. But there is a problem with non-domain users. When you open a site page that makes an api call, a basic authentication window appears. I use the `auth_gss_allow_basic_fallback off` directive, but this does not help.

How can I disable this and configure redirection to `/auth`?

My configuration file (I do not specify settings such as gzip, headers, etc.):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  srv-01.example.com;

    proxy_set_header remote-user $remote_user;

    location / {
        root /opt/site/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /adminpanel {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.4:4567;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.4:4567;

    auth_gss on;
    auth_gss_realm EXAMPLE.COM;
    auth_gss_keytab /etc/krb5.keytab;
    auth_gss_service_name HTTP/srv-01.example.com;
    auth_gss_allow_basic_fallback off;
    }}
```

Comment: You could add a `location /auth` so that the `/auth` URI does not hit the same `if` statement.

Comment: @RichardSmith, Thanks for the answer, but that did not help. Supplemented the question with additional information.